# Sitecore forms - display fields one after the other

Tags: sitecore-forms

I have a sitecore form with 6 questions which are radio button options yes/no. If first question is answered, only then display 2nd question and then etc. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can achieve that with OOTB functionality of Sitecore forms.

Place second radio button inside a `Section` form element.

On the section use conditional rendering to only show the section when first radio button has chosen value - you can combine "yes"/"no" options with `or` condition if you want:

[image]